# How to get the same element after comparison?

Tags: jquery

I get a url parameter and comparison it with object's attribute. If is there a such element, I want add class to this. How I can get this? Thanks!

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
let params = window.location.search;
if(params != "") {

    let sort, way;
    sort = url.searchParams.get("sort");
    way = url.searchParams.get("way");

    if (sort != null) {

        if ($(".header").children().attr("parameter") == sort) {
            /* here */ $(".header").children().addClass("active");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? `$(".header").children()` is the same element when you check the attribute as when you add the class.

Comment: The `if` line doesn't search all the children for a matching attribute. It tests the attribute of the first child.

Comment: @Barmar I have some lines with class .header which have an one child with different parameters. I want to find one and change one. My code works bad, because it find one, but edits all.

Comment: The `if` will only be true if the first child has the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rely on the query selector to only add the class if the correct attribute exists like this:

```
$('.header').children(`[parameter="${sort}"]`).addClass('active');
```

Comment: The second solution is no different from the OP's except you are caching

Comment: I removed the second "solution", I misunderstood what OP was asking.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Where I can read more about such way with using `[parameter="${sort}"]`    ? And how it names?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget remove class from other elements. This code might be called several times with different `sort` value or class `active` might come from server.

```
$(".header").children().removeClass('active')
   .filter("[parameter=" + sort + "]").addClass('active');
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiger/x7w21u4f/13/)